# Kivy Not Rendering Kv File

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to load a Kivy file that looks like this

```
#application.kv
<Grid>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Name: "

            TextInput:
                multinline:False

            Label:
                text: "Email: "

            TextInput:
                multiline:False

        Button:
            text:"Submit"
            on_press: app.btn()
```

And my code looks like

```
class Grid(Widget):
    pass
class Application(App):

    
    def build(self):
        
        kv=Builder.load_file('application.kv')
        return kv
app=Application()
app.run()
```

But when I run the code I get a blank screen.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `kv` file dos not define a root widget. It only define a rule that describes how to build a `Grid` widget (but dos not build one). You can fix that by changing:

```
<Grid>:
```

to:

```
Grid:
```

Answer (score 0):

As John Anderson said in his answer, you **defined** the widget but not **create** the widget. At the end of your script, just create the widget with `Grid:`.